# Is this code legal? (C++0x move semantics)

Tags: c++, c++11, perfect-forwarding

I'm curious as to whether this code is legal in C++0x. Specifically, will the object declared in the function `move_it()` be properly moved to the object declared in `main()`?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <tr1/memory>
using namespace std;

class x
{
public:
    x() { cout << "create " << this << endl; }
    ~x() { cout << "destroy " << this << endl; }
};

x&& move_it()
{
    x r;
    return move(r);
}

int main()
{
    x n = move_it();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you try compiling it? Did it have errors? what is the issue here?

Comment: Not only it's always an error returning reference (any reference) to local object from function, it never makes sense returning rvalue reference from a function (except in cases like static_cast and std::move).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, it is returning  a reference to a local object, just like with an lvalue reference.

Just return it by value and let x's assumed move constructor pick up the rvalue. When you return by value, the returned object is an rvalue.

If you are lucky, the NRVO optimization will kick in (just like before) and elide the copying anyway.

Answer (score 3):

You are returning a dangling rvalue reference from `move_it`, which invokes undefined behavior when you access it in `main`.

If you want to move the object, change the return type to `x` and get rid of the move:

```
x move_it()
{
    x r;
    return r;
}
```

(Automatic variables are implicitly treated as rvalues when returned from a function.)

Comment: @Flame: Not sure what you mean. I meant that when you say `return x;` and `x` is a local variable, then the compiler will treat the lvalue `x` is if it were an rvalue. No need to `move` explicitly.

Comment: @Flame: no, `r` is an lvalue, but compiler first tries to elide copy, if failed, it moves it, if failed again -- copies it.

Comment: @Flame: The expression `move_it()` is a *prvalue* if you return an `x`, and it is an *xvalue* if you return an `x&&`. Both prvalues and xvalues are rvalues. But this has nothing to do with the compiler treating returned automatic variables as if they were rvalues.

Answer (score 1):

As a regular user, anyone not implementing a template library, the only use for r-value references you should make is in implementing move constructors and move assignment.

Check out this video http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/C9-Lectures-Stephan-T-Lavavej-Standard-Template-Library-STL-9-of-n

Comment: Not really, for move ctors and assignments often defaults are correct, but when it comes to other functions it is exactly where you might need them. In fact `template<class T> ... foo(T&&)` is the most common case.